# Android viewflipper: how to auto flip, play text-to-speech and flip

Tags: android, text-to-speech, viewflipper

I have some troubles on viewflipper and tts. What I want to do is using viewflipper to display a series of word and play tts one by one. Firstly, I set AnimiationListener for viewflipper and play TTS in onAnimationEnd(). Secondly, I set setOnUtteranceProgressListener() for TTS and try to call viewflipper.showNext() in onDone() event. But I get the following errors. It seems the viewflipper instance is not accessable in TTS. Anyone can give me hints to solve this or any other ways can do the samethings?

Error messages

```
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:2588)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:608)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8429)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5714)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.showOnly(ViewAnimator.java:159)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.showOnly(ViewAnimator.java:179)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(ViewAnimator.java:111)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.widget.ViewAnimator.showNext(ViewAnimator.java:130)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at com.example.reading.TTS_Play$3.onDone(TTS_Play.java:305)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection$1.onDone(TextToSpeech.java:1264)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechCallback$Stub.onTransact(ITextToSpeechCallback.java:63)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:351)
02-14 12:00:44.934: E/JavaBinder(3321):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

trigger TTS when viewflipper animation end

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    flipper.stopFlipping();
    String utteranceID = "some messages";  
    playTTS(utteranceID); // play tts
}
```

init TTS and show first view on viewflipper

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    setTtsListener(tts); // set TTS listener
    flipper.stopFlipping(); // stop viewflipper to auto flip
    String utteranceID = "some messages";  
    playTTS(utteranceID); // play tts
}
```

play TTS

```
private void playTTS(String utteranceID) {
    View v = flipper.getCurrentView();
    TextView tv_tts = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_tts);       
    HashMap<String, String> ttsHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ttsHashMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceID);    
    tts.speak(tv_tts.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, ttsHashMap);
}
```

listener for TTS

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setTtsListener(TextToSpeech tts) {
    this.tts = tts;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15) {
        int listenerResult = this.tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(
            new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
//                      this.onDone(utteranceId);
                    flipper.showNext(); // <-- throws errors here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                }
            });

        if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "failed to add utterance progress listener");
        }
    } else {
        int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(
            new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {
//                  this.onDone(utteranceId);
                flipper.showNext();
            }
        });

        if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "failed to add utterance completed listener");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134766/how-to-access-layout-in-tts-onutterancecompleted-callback). I will try it out later.

Comment: that's link works for me